# Perform 'cross product' of two vectors, but with addition

Tags: r, cross-product

I am trying to use R to perform an operation (ideally with similarly displayed output) such as

```
> x<-1:6
> y<-1:6
> x%o%y
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30
[6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36
```

where each entry is found through addition not multiplication.

I would also be interested in creating the 36 ordered pairs (1,1) , (1,2), etc...

Furthermore, I want to use another vector like

```
z<-1:4
```

to create all the ordered triplets possible between x, y, and z.

I am using R to look into likelihoods of possible total when rolling dice with varied numbers of sizes.

Thank you for all your help! This site has been a big help to me. I appreciate anyone that takes the time to answer a stranger's question.

**UPDATE** So I found that `outer(x,y,'+') will do what I wanted first. But I still don't know how to create ordered pairs or ordered triplets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`expand.grid` can answer your second question:

```
expand.grid(1:6,1:6)
expand.grid(1:6,1:6,1:4)
```

Comment: Thank you! THis is exactly what I want. My students will be pleased tomorrow!

Answer (score 15):

Your first question is easily handled by `outer`:

```
outer(1:6,1:6,"+")
```

For the others, I suggest you try `expand.grid`, although there are specialized combination and permutation functions out there as well if you do a little searching.

Comment: Booo, you edited before the first 5 minutes, so it looks like I just swiped your answer... ;-)

Comment: Joshua did not swipe my answer! Thanks for the help! Do you know of a good place to find functions like these? I have the r reference card, but I don't think `outer' is on there.

Comment: @Josua - Sorry 'bout that; I knew `outer` right of the top of my head and then went back to see if there was something better than `expand.grid`...I shouldn't be in such a hurry for rep! ;)

Comment: @joran: I'm just kidding.  You've been providing very useful answers.  Keep it up and the reputation will come.